# Primefaces show animation when button clicked

Tags: primefaces

I have the following button and panel in primefaces:

```xml
<p:commandButton value="Submit"
    ajax="true" actionListener="#{myBean.search}" update="resultPanel" oncomplete="panelwv.show();">
</p:commandButton>

<p:panel widgetVar="panelwv" visible="false" closable="true"
    toggleable="true" id="resultPanel">
```

I want while the myBean.search executes, an animation appears on the screen.
Any help?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [Primefaces AJAX - Status - Declarative](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml)

> Ajax Status is a global indicator to inform users about the ajax interactions. By default ajax requests trigger the ajaxStatus component, setting global to false disables this behavior.

also take a look at the other examples [Primefaces AJAX - Status](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/status.xhtml)

Just place some nice image in the `h:graphicImage`

You can generate one using the [Ajaxload - Ajax loading gif generator](http://ajaxload.info/)