# Visual "busy" indication in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a Primefaces-based application, in which there are some lengthy operations.

When such operation is being executed, I want to indicate this somehow (like displaying an hourglass or a message, which appears at the center of the screen).

What is the easiest way to do this in Primefaces/JSF?

Comment: If the operations are AJAX calls, you could use [`<p:ajaxStatus>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatus.jsf)

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13139815/617373

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it with `<p:blockUI>`. Here's an example:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="content" >
        ...
        <p:commandButton id="longOperation" value="Process" />
    </p:panel>
    <p:blockUI block="content" trigger="longOperation">  
        <p>Here you can customize what appears as the overlay over the blocked content.</p>
        <p:graphicImage value="/images/ajax-loader.gif"/>  
    </p:blockUI>
</h:form>
```

Take a look at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf for more info.

Comment: Let's say I have `<p:blockUI id="buttonPanelBlockUI" block="buttonPanel" ...>` statement in my XHTML code. How can I unblock the panel `buttonPanel` from inside my Java code?

Comment: You don't, you return from your Java code, at which point JSF will render the response and in turn your blocked content will unblock. The content is automatically unblocked as soon as the request started by the `<p:commandButton />` completes.

Comment: blockUI is no longer in primefaces

Comment: Still listed in the showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml